# Cloning GitHub repository in Visual Studio for Mac 17.0

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-mac

I tried cloning my GitHub repository using Visual Studio for Mac 17.0 and got the username/password screen. Once I entered them, I got an error message stating I need to use my Personal Access Token which is fine but VS no longer asks for my username or password/token. It just automatically gives me the error.

How do I set/change them in Visual Studio for Mac OR macOS? I'm not a Mac person and renting one so things are not so obvious for me though this maybe a fairly simple question.

Comment: For macOS *in general*, keys (passwords, tokens, whatever) get stored in the mac "keychain". Whether VS follows mac conventions, I don't know, but check the [macOS keychain](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-keychains-to-store-passwords-mchlf375f392/mac).